# segmentation fault in C++

Tags: c++

i am facing problem for input `1000000011,5`.

The output should be: `5000000058`.

I am facing segmentation fault error.

```
#include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
    int c,r;
    cin>>r>>c;
    cout<<endl;
    int k;
    if(r%2==1)
 {
    k= 10*(r/2)+2*(c-1);
  }
    else if(r%2==0)
 {
    k=10*(r/2-1)+(2*(c-1)+1);
  }
    cout<<k;
    return 0;
  }
```

`

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: you enter both numbers like this: 1000000011<comma>5 ?

Comment: Add `cout<<r<<c<<endl;` after the `cin` to see if you read the values correctly, because nothing else can cause a segmentation fault

Comment: I find it hard to believe that that code can cause a segmentation fault. (It does produce a [very different result](http://ideone.com/5gFEKs), though, because you haven't considered the magnitude of the result.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing overflow, not segmentation fault.

`5000000058` simply just doesn't fit into 32-bit int that is used. You should use a type that uses more bits to store value.

In this particular case changing to `long long` should do the trick.

Change `int c,r;` to `long long c,r;` and `int k;` to `long long k;` and it works as intended.